# i am able to send message for indian number using amazon sns but for us number iam not able send message

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

async sendMessage(testId: number) {
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

```
const sns = new AWS.SNS();

const message = {
  Message: 'This is the SMS message I want to send.',
  PhoneNumber: '+15876851230',//dummy number
};

sns.publish(message, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Message published successfully!');
  }
});
```

}

```
how to fix this error in aws sns it is showing just failed
```

i want to send message for us number

Answer (score 0):

Did you moved from the sandbox? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sms-sandbox-verifying-phone-numbers.html

Tbh, you don't provide enough informations, but I assume that verified idp would solve your problem if you already moved from sandbox - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities.html

> There's no additional charge for using sender IDs. However, support and requirements for sender ID authentication varies. Several major markets (including Canada, China, and the United States) don't support using sender IDs. Some areas require that companies who send SMS messages to individual customers must use a sender ID that's pre-registered with a regulatory agency or industry group.

Comment: hi sir what are additional details you needed

Comment: hello, I mean about a configuration of SNS - this two topics from my answer